# iCloud for saving fairly frequent game state changes

Tags: ios, icloud

i want to implement iCloud into my app: Its a short game. One round takes 3-5 minutes and after that you get xp, coins or whatever. Its really just 5 key-value-pairs and is only updated after every round. Syncing problems aside, [apples documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html) states:

> The key-value store is intended for storing data that changes
>   infrequently. If the apps on a device make frequent changes to the key-value store, the system may defer the synchronization of some changes in order to minimize the number of round trips to the server. The more frequently apps make changes, the more likely it is that later changes will be deferred and not show up on other devices right away.

Given the simplicity and size of my data i would still go for the key-value-storage but after i read this i am not too sure about it. [Apple suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html) Document storage for complex app states and Key-value storage for simple app states. 
So my question is:

When the data changes this frequently, is it better to use document storage, even if my data is that simple?

Comment: FYI, i used a document storage now, because it has no disadvantages except that it is slightly more complicated to implement. And if the syncinc capabilities should be better (i dont think they are worse) i have that on the plus side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key value it's a mess. It doesn't sync quickly with icloud, the sync is controlled by the operating system. So frustrating.
Go with document/core data